# Head covering for women

Tags: gentiles

It's known that for a gentile to perform the mitzvot commanded for the Jews is a sin; but modesty is a law for all the nations. So is a female gentile allowed to cover her hair?

Comment: I'd assume its ok. First of all, covering hair isn't clearly a Biblical law (neither is the amount that needs to be covered). Second, modesty is logical thing to have, so it should be ok. Third, a non-Jew can do many mitzvoth for their own benefit, as long as they don't do it with the exact details Jews do it or if they don't do it as a religious obligation (but rather as a voluntary service). The last 2 points are based on The Divine Code (by Rabbi Moshe Weiner) Chapter 3: Fundamentals of Faith.

Comment: An additional consideration is when Jews live among Gentiles. In that case it is preferable for the gentiles to dress modestly to protect Jewish men from sin. On a side note, it is humiliating to our glorious people that many Jewish women, in Jerusalem (and other parts of Israel) today, dress immodestly, whereas the Muslim women are dressed appropriately.

Comment: Your very welcome! I am happy to help.

Comment: "but modesty is a law for all the nations" How do you know this?

Answer (score 2):

There are only two commandments that are clearly forbidden to gentiles, namely, Sabbath and Torah-study.  Most (if not all) other commandments are not only permitted, but meritorious (see, e.g., Sanhedrin 48b; Maimonides Laws of Kings 10:10). Hair covering, as an act of modesty, would be no more a Jew-specific commandment than covering any other part of the body that would be considered immodest if left exposed.

Comment: Not sure of this answer... Can they wear tefilin? Keep pesach? Bring a non-olah? Pretty sure that's a no for all three...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Fair enough (though I think some of those might be more mitzad the Jews involved, not specifically a prohibition on the gentile). Edited accordingly.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Why can't they wear tefillin or keep pesach (sans korbanot)?

Comment: @DoubleAA why can't they keep shabbos or learn Torah? Those aren't explicitly prohibited in the text...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't know what text you refer to but yes they are explicitly prohibited in the Gemara and Rambam.

Comment: @DoubleAA correct. The gemara prohibited it based upon what? It's a drash from what principles (rather than explicitly in a possuk)?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't know what you are getting at.

Answer (score 0):

One of the 7 Noahide Laws to which any gentile is obligated is to establish courts/legal system to ensure law and obedience (it is the 7th according to the Rambam). Thus a gentile in a Muslim state that acts according to their set of laws including head covering in such and such manner would be obligatory for the weman of that state.